# How to check test RegEx pattern to exactly match a specific URL domain?

Tags: regex, url

I am searching for a clean way to write a regular expression to match urls **ONLY** with a URL domain named here as `www.mysite.com`, only varying the prefix and suffix. So this RegEx must match  these cases:

`http://www.mysite.com/mycoolpage.html`
`http://www.mysite.com/mycoolpage.aspx?a_querystring=ABC123`
`http://www.mysite.com/mycoolpage.aspx?a_querystring=ABC123&another_querystring=ABC123`
`http://www.mysite.com/anothercoolpage.asp?a_querystring=ABC123`
`http://mysite.com/anothercoolpage.asp?a_querystring=ABC123`

The regular expression must deal with any file: `html, asp, aspx, etc`.
Also the `a_querystring` can be of any possible value: `xyz=123, a=Boston, q=a%20big%20value`

Is there a readable way to write this Regular expression so developers can easily understand?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
~http://(?:.*\.)?mysite\.com\S*~
```

**Explanation:**

```
~         : regex delimiter
http://   : literaly http://
(?:       : non capture group
.*\.      : any number of any char followed by dot
}?        : end of group optional
mysite    : literaly mysite
\.        : a dot
com       : literaly com
\S*       : any number of non white spaces
~         : regex delimiter
```

Comment: that will match `http://www.thatsnotmysite.com` :) you need to add a \.  before mysite\.com

Answer (score 1):

This regex will work:

```
#http://(?:.*\.)*mysite\.com(?:/|$)*#
```

[Example](https://xrg.es/#11emsn6)

Answer (score 0):

`grep http://[^\.]*\.mysite\..* *`

The "any file" comes from the final `*`. The pattern itself says "start with `http://`, then any number of characters *that aren't a literal .*, then a literal dot, then "mysite" and a literal dot, then anything."

Comment: That wasn't given as a test it had to match.